# Adding split line as array of array ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, lines

I'm comparing lines in quite large file ("link_lines") with lines containing multiple columns like this:

```
1245598 1245716 506074  506198  119     119     93.60   0.00    0.01    LG01  scf_1
```

Let's say that the file is 100,000 lines long, and all have the same setup. The last two columns specify genomic locations, and I first have to iterate over the file for each LG and each scf to get only the lines containing the same values in these two columns into an array to compare these further. The first is simple enough with (having a made a list of each all LGs and scfs):

```
temp_links = []
unique_lgs.each do |lg| 
    unique_scaffold_hits.each do |scf|
        link_lines.each do |l|
            if l.to_s.split[9] == lg && l.to_s.split[10] == scf
            temp_links << l
```

The problem is now to sort all lines in "temp_lines" on column 7. 
I've made some progress with `l.split.to_a` for the last line, but this does not seem to create the array of arrays that I hoped for (and though would be easier to work with...).

Any help on how to get these lines sorted correctly is much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Having tested out different methods of sort on simpler arrays I see that I might not have been concise enough. So just in case it was not clear what I wanted as output, here's a more comprehensive example. The "temp_links" looks like this:

```
124559 1245716 506074  506198  200   119  93.60   0.00    0.01    LG01  scf_1
985787 9859674 419493  419674  100   300  92.90   0.00    0.02    LG01  scf_1
840174 8401886 677169  677347  300   500  93.89   0.00    0.02    LG01  scf_1
```

And the desired output would be

```
840174 8401886 677169  677347  300   500  93.89   0.00    0.02    LG01  scf_1  
124559 1245716 506074  506198  200   119  93.60   0.00    0.01    LG01  scf_1 
985787 9859674 419493  419674  100   300  92.90   0.00    0.02    LG01  scf_1
```

so simply sorted on the largest value of column 5 amongst the lines.

I have then tried to only output the numbers of interest, for simplicity and
`puts temp_links.split[4]` works, but `puts temp_links.split[4].sort` returns  `“undefined method sort for "100":String (NoMethodError)”`

Again, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but l.split should be returning an array already, temp_links << l.split should give you the array of arrays you are looking for, right?

Comment: If the file is 100,000 lines, have you considered using the `sort` command in your OS to first sort the file, then use Ruby to extract the data? That will be much faster and will use the tools best suited for particular tasks.

Comment: @jdussault: That's what I originally hoped for, but when printed the structure is 
    `[["a","b","c"]][["a","b","c"]][["a","b","c"]]`
and not 
    `[["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"],["a","b","c"]]`
so not sure what's going on there...

Comment: @theTinMan: Sure thing!  `sort -k10, -k11, k5n`  would get me there, and I'm sure `awk` would too, but this is part of a larger ruby script, and I was hoping to find a good way to do it with ruby :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to sort an array of arrays by a particular element in the sub-arrays:

```
lines = [%[3 4], %[1 2]] # => ["3 4", "1 2"]
aoa = lines.map(&:split) # => [["3", "4"], ["1", "2"]]
aoa.sort{ |a, b| a[1] <=> b[1] } # => [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"]]
```

`aoa.sort...` will return an instance of the sorted array.

Comment: Thanks, but as I don't seem to get the aoa from `l.split`or `.map` then I'm none the wiser...But I'f I were to get an aoa from these, should not something like this work then:     `temp_links_sorted = temp_links.sort_by{|a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,| e }`

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "0.01  LG01 scf_1
0.20  LG02 scf_1
0.02  LG01 scf_1
1.00  LG02 scf_2
1.00  LG02 scf_1"

grouped = str.lines.map(&:chomp).group_by do |line|
  line.split.values_at(-2,-1)
end

puts grouped

# =>
#{["LG01", "scf_1"]=>["0.01  LG01 scf_1", "0.02  LG01 scf_1"],
# ["LG02", "scf_1"]=>["0.20  LG02 scf_1", "1.00  LG02 scf_1"],
# ["LG02", "scf_2"]=>["1.00  LG02 scf_2"]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm probably to stupid too see how this grouping would help me sort the desired lines, and eventually output the full original lines again. Sorry.